# c++ memory management

Tags: c++, memory, pointers, new-operator

Is this a good way to delete a map of longs and objects made with new

```
// iterate over the map
for (std::map<unsigned long, Object*>::iterator it = objects.begin(), it_end = objects.end(); it != it_end; ++it)
{
    Object* temp = it->second;
    if(temp)
        delete temp;
}

// clear the map
objects.clear();
```

Comment: Provided that each entry has been new-ed separately (or in other words that there are not two entries with the same value of pointer to object), it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, although the better solution would be to use smart pointers instead of `Object*`, but that is a different subject.

You could shorten the content of the for to

```
{
   delete it->second;
}
```

`delete null` is defined and is a noop.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Use boost::ptr_map

```
boost::ptr_map<std::string, BigObject>   data;

data.insert("Plop", new BigObject);
```

When data goes out of scope it deletes all its `value` members.
Also for algorithms all members are returned as reference to the object (not pointer) thus it is much easier to use with the standard algorithms than a std::map<std::string, BigObject*> where you would need to de-reference the memebrs before use.

One would have to question why you have a map of pointer to int/long in the first place? Would it not be easier to just to store the value in the map?

Comment: His map doesn't store pointers to int/long, but to `Object` classes. I presume it's done for polymorphism.

Comment: @sven yes this is correct.  My company is very scared of change and I doubt they will allow me to include boost.  Thanks for the help though

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm: boost is practically standard. The boost organization was set up by members so the C++ committee explicitly as a proving ground for things that would likely make it into a future standard. As a result it is one of the most test (trusted) extensions to the standard you can find. Look through the C++ answers on SO; a good majority will have a boost solution that already solved the problem.

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm: you may be able to use use C++0x smart pointers as per my answer. `std::unique_ptr` works on VC2010 and g++ 4.6, and if you have g++ 4.5 you can use `std::shared_ptr` (although `std::unique_ptr` is supported by g++ 4.5, `std::map` is not yet move-aware so you can't use it with that; this was fixed in 4.6).

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm: It just makes your life a lot easier in the long run. It makes your code more readable, easier to maintain, and safer (particularly with regard to exception safety). Of course, it's your decision. :)

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm; Too me it seems like overkill that you are doing all this work manually. You should never have to call delete. If you use the correct objects then memory management is automatic. Pointers are a sure sign that you will get it wrong at some point (**because their is no ownership semantics associated with a pointer**) smart pointers and containers make sure your code is easy to read and exception safe and the specific smart pointer is a way of documenting ownership.

Comment: PS. Have you take into account that you can not copy or assign your map without significant danger. Has your interface that exposes your map made sure that future maintainers are aware that it can not be copied. Have you made sure that if a maintainer changes the code in a bad way the compiler generates an error?

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm; Have you noticed that **EVERY** answer apart from your accepted one is indicating that you should use some form of smart pointer or container.

Comment: someones bitter. Mario's answer is the one i was looking for sorry.

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm: It makes no difference to me which you choose. 'Sven' answer below is a perfectly good solution. But the fact that you picked the answer you were expecting rather than than an answer that will improve your code (as indicated by the community response) is an indication ... (mostly that you are not aware on the concept of ownership semantics)   (I am sure you have considered the implications of the "Rule of three" on your code) :-)

Comment: Martin you are obviously very active on this site and I can tell you know your stuff.  But, Mario's answer is what helped me the most in my situation.  I up-voted your answer as well as others that provided good information. Also, How does this pertain to the rule of three? I have a destructor which sets a pointer to NULL and a delete function which is necessary to have for the user interaction.  2!=3

Comment: @Kaiser Wilhelm: Rule of three: `If you have to define any of "Destructor/Copy Constructor/Assignment operator" then you probably need to define all three`. In this case if your class contains a std::map that contains owned pointers you better define the copy constructor/assignment operator (at least disable them). As any copy made of your class is going to cause undefined behavior when that copy is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

It is a perfectly fine way to delete.

Though you can make your life much easier by using a smart pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good start.

Once you've deleted the object, you should either remove the pointer from the map or set it to NULL to avoid dangling pointers. Edit: or of course you could just clear out the map when you're done, as your example shows.

When you store pointers in any of the standard containers, there's always a possibility that an exception or some code error will result in a memory leak. I'd suggest [boost pointer containers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html) as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Regardless of what might be considered a design or architecture issue (the use of smarter pointers, for example), it is not unreasonable to use that method to clear the map.

One proviso:  the `objects` map should not by changed by the destruction of the Object* pointers.  If it is, it might be better to use something like this:

```
// iterate over the map
typedef std::map<unsigned long, Object*>::iterator map_iter;
for (map_iter it = objects.begin();
    it != objects.end();
    /* blank */ )
{
    iter_map to_delete = it;
    ++it;
    Object* temp = to_delete->second;
    if(temp)
        delete temp;
    objects.delete(to_delete);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the use of a smart pointer, for example `std::unique_ptr` (this is a C++0x feature, not all compilers support it yet). For example:

```
std::map<unsigned long, std::unique_ptr<Object>> map;
// Do something with the map
map.clear(); // The objects are automatically deleted.
```

You can also use `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr` if your compiler doesn't support C++0x smart pointers), which has the advantage that it will work if your map can contain the same pointer more than once, and your objects won't be destroyed if someone else still has a pointer to them.

`boost::ptr_map` is also an options, though I believe that, like the manual approach, will not work right if the map contains the same pointer more than once.